# jquery sliding hidden content line break

Tags: jquery, css, animation, sliding

I'm trying to do this     [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mqzuD/10/)

EDIT ---   <strike>here's the current situation with placeholders [problem demo]</strike>[2] --- EDIT

for some reason my text is line breaking and then jumping up to inline after the animation   is finished. I can't use the plain 'div' because it affects the rest of the page so I'm unsure how to get this thing to work properly.

my code is literally exactly as shown in the demo minus the div display inline block css rule

```
div {
display : inline-block;
}
.holdingbox {
position: relative;
top: 0;
}
.leftbox {
position: relative;
top: 0;
left:0;
display:inline-block;
}
.rightbox {
position: relative;
display:inline-block;
overflow:hidden;
width:0;
height:30px;
vertical-align:top;
}
.content{
width:100px;
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
}
.box {
margin-left : 5px;
}
```

​
html is

```
<div class="holdingbox">
 <span class="leftbox">Stuff</span>
 <span class="rightbox">
     <span class="content">Stuff to reveal</span>
 </span>
</div>
<div class = "box">Text</div>​
```

and js is

```
    $('.holdingbox').hover(function(){
    $('.rightbox').animate({width: '90px'}, 1000)
}, function(){
    $('.rightbox').animate({width: '0'}, 1000)
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mqzuD/27/ you want this?

Comment: from what I can tell, they are the same effect - and they still seem to have the same effect when I put them into my page. I'll upload my code so you can see what's occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new css rule

`.inline_block {
    display : inline-block;
}`

and add it where needed e.g.

```
<div class="holdingbox inline_block">
 <span class="leftbox inline_block">Stuff</span>
  <span class="rightbox inline_block">
  <span class="content inline_block">Stuff to reveal</span>
 </span>
</div>
<div class = "box inline_block">Text</div>​
```

This should not affect other `divs` on the page.

Comment: Ok I've figured it out, change `position: relative;` inside `.leftbox {..}` and `.rightbox {}` with `float: left;`

Comment: it seems to now animate in the right place (except in chrome) but it drops down once that is finished. It does work in firefox consistently, but in safari it only works if the width of .rightbox in the js is less than the width of the the content of .rightbox

Comment: Chrome doesn't like `display: inline-block;` change it to `display: inline;` this should help. Not sure about Safai, but you can set some `padding` and this could do the trick for you.

Comment: that solved it - I had been trying padding etc but the trick was the inline-block rule for .holdingbox thanks so much for your help